# tinymce.ui simple text component

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce a trying to extend a plugin to show a dialog with specific layout:

```
 editor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Title of my dialog',
        body: [
            {type: 'label', text: 'my label'},
            { name:'my_input', type: 'textbox'},
        //  {  type: 'text', html:'some content with <b>bold</b> if posilbe!'},
            //  {  type: 'html', value:'<div>with custom formating</div>'}
        ]
    }
```

I checked the  the documentation for [tinymce.ui](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3anamespace.tinymce.ui) several times but can find a way to add html or text component in the constructor of the dialog (like the comment rows in the example).

I know there is a option using a ready html template for the dialog.. but there are also a lot of events and triggers so using the constructor and .ui components is more suitable for my case.

Answer (score 5):

I used to use JQuery UI dialog for this but ran into some issues after TinyMCE 4.0.

I have a TinyMCE plugin that lets people fetch the plain text version of their post in the WordPress editor. Then I show them that text using this:

```
var plain_block = {
    type: 'container',
     html: '<textarea style="margin: 10px; width: 550px !important; height: 450px !important; background-color: #eee;" readonly="readonly">Whatever plain text I need to show goes here</textarea>'
};

ed.windowManager.open({
    title: "Plain Text of This Post",
    spacing: 10,
    padding: 10,
    items: [
     plain_block
    ],
     buttons: [
     {
           text: "Close", 
           onclick: function() { ed.windowManager.close();}
         }
    ]
});
```

End result is a pretty plain-jane dialog box with some HTML and a Close button